# Need help understanding passing arguments to function

Tags: c++, c, function, parameters, arguments

I’m new to C++ and unsure about how to pass arguments to functions.

I’m using a function `Distance()` to calculate the distance between two nodes.
I declare the function like this:

```
int Distance(int x1, int y1, int x2 , int y2)
{   
    int distance_x = x1-x2;
    int distance_y = y1- y2; 
    int distance = sqrt((distance_x * distance_x) + (distance_y * distance_y));
    return distance; 
}
```

In the main memory I have 2 `for` loops.
What I need to know is if I can pass the values like this: `Distance (i, j, i+1, j+1)`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < No_Max; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < No_Max; j++)
    {
        if(Distance(i, j, i+1, j+1) <= Radio_Range) // the function 
            node_degree[i] = node_degree[i] + 1;

        cout << node_degree[i] << endl;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Is there some reason you think it's not right?

Comment: To get a more accurate distance value, your function should return a floating point type, such as `double`.

Comment: You might not want to convert the result of `sqrt` to `int` like that.

Comment: If your program isn't working, make sure you're explicit about the error you're getting.  Also, be a bit more clear in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Arguments to functions can be supplied as any expression which matches the type of that argument or can be cast to it.

Answer (score 2):

Tips : 
You should use double instead of int if you want to use sqrt :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/sqrt/

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you are calling your `Distance(int, int, int, int)` function correctly. 
The following statement will call `Distance()`:

```
Distance (i, j, i+1, j+1);
```

This will store the value returned by `Distance()` in a variable:

```
int dist = Distance (i, j, i+1, j+1);
```

This will compare the value returned by `Distance()` (the left operand) to `Radio_Range` (the right operand). If the left operand is less than or equal to the right operand, it will be evaluated to `1` (true). Otherwise it will be `0` (false). If the overall value of the expression inside the `if` statement is non-zero, the statement or block immediately following the `if` statement will be executed:

```
if(Distance(i, j, i+1, j+1) <= Radio_Range)
   //Statement;
```

or:

```
if(Distance(i, j, i+1, j+1) <= Radio_Range){
   //Statement;
   //Statement;
   //...
}
```

However, the value returned by `Distance()` will be truncated to an integer. Thus, `distance` will not equal the actual distance unless `(distance_x * distance_x) + (distance_y * distance_y)` is a perfect square. For better precision, consider using a `double`. If you intend to have the function return an `int`, it would be wise to do an explicit type cast, e.g.:

```
int distance = (int)sqrt((distance_x * distance_x) + (distance_y * distance_y));
```

This will ensure that if you or anyone else looks at the code later on, they will not think the function is using the wrong data type.